# Access each header and controls in the tableview in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, header, nstableheaderview

I have a `UITableView` with customized header. In that header I have a button with image.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))

    itemNumBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 42))
    itemNumBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "hide.png"), forState: .Normal)
    cView.addSubview(itemNumBtn)

    return cView
}
```

I have five header secion.

in separate function how can get the image of the each button, need to access each button

Ex:

```
fun getHeader() {
    // how to access each header and buttons
    var eachBtn = each button in the header
    var image = all the images of all header section
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get `button` and `image` from `header`, you can implement a customized `UIView` for `header`, like

```
class HeaderView: UIView {
    var button: UIButton
    var image: UIImage

    func init() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And return this `HeaderView` in your `tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)` callback.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return HeaderView()
}
```

Then use `tableView.headerViewForSection(section:)` to get 5 customized headers view.

```
func getHeaders() {

    for index in 1...5 {
         let header = tableView.headerViewForSection(section: index) as! HeaderView
         let button = header.button
         let image = header.image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but instead of subclassing view i used UITableViewHeaderFooterView