# Elements not connecting to the view

Tags: ios, swift

why am I not able to connect the element such as label and button to the UIView class I have created.I have named it in the storyboard as well.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Rob I linked the view to my TableViewController file as an IBOutlet

Comment: You could simply check the this link to get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/33007472/5089923

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access each header and controls in the tableview in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007142/access-each-header-and-controls-in-the-tableview-in-swift)

Comment: @ShubhDev I have section headers as well so this is confusing me.Apart from that I too tried creating a UIView class for the view but couldn't connect those switch and label in to it.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, then connect outlets from IB/Storyboard.

Then you can access these through `viewForHeaderInSection` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomHeader") as! CustomHeader

headerView.Label.text = "View all calls"

return headerView
}
```

Comment: but shouldn't I connect the view to my TableviewController file

Comment: Can you edit your original post with the code you've got so far?